# ServiceStack ORM Lite calling a stored procedure with more than one parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ORM Lite's .SqlList method to call a stored procedure and map the results to my custom object. When I am using only one parameter, and calling the stored procedure as follow it works fine:

```
var results = conn.SqlList<CustomObject>("EXEC MyStoredProcedure @paramOne"), new { paramOne = "someParam" });
```

When I want to call a stored procedure with more than one parameter and I call it as shown bellow I get an error stating that "The given key was not present in the dictionary.".

```
var results = conn.SqlList<CustomObject>("EXEC MyStoredProcedure @paramOne, @paramTwo"), new { paramOne = "someParam", paramTwo = "someOtherParam" });
```

I had a look at the sql stored procedure test page on the ORM Lite Github repo but it does not show how to call stored procedures with more that one param.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I should add that the second parameter on the sql side is a custom table type, and I am sending in a DataTable type in C#.

Comment: Syntax looks correct to me. Your custom table type parameters may be the issue. You may want to add example of the SQL table definition, and the C# parameter with the same type, instead of a string.

Comment: I'm trying to do something very similar, @FreddieGericke have you had any luck? Also, it looks like you have an extra bracket at the end of your "EXEC" statement.